# Is it possible to disabled the button after the form is submitted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm using jquery to avoid multiple form submission and basically disable the button on click. A bad consequence seems to be that the form is no longer submitted, thus the question: Is it possible to disable the button but still submit the form ? I know I can do the form submission through jQuery but currently all the requests are server side processed (e.g. after the form is submitted it returns a full html page either with the error or success response)

Here is the code I have so far

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        setTimeout(function(){alert("Hello")}, 3000);

        $("#loginBtn").click(function() {
            $("#loginBtn").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }); // click()
    }); // ready()
</script>
  <form id="myForm">
    <div class="form-actions">

        <input id="loginBtn"    class="btn btn-primary"  type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
```

**Edit**
Just to make sure it's clear: The form **is not** submitted through AJAX

Comment: Where is your `<form>` tag?

Comment: You need to use ajax for it you can perform an action with ajax post and on success change button property to enable..

Comment: If you still want to submit the form as normal, there is absolutely no need to disable the button - the page will unload anyway.

Comment: @YairNevet I've edited the question and added the <form> tag

Comment: @Priyajain I don't want to use ajax post. I think the question is  quite clear.

Comment: @Bergi What are you talking about ? unload ?? I'm trying to avoid the double click issues (i.e. on checkout /payment buttons )

Comment: why do you need the button be disabled? when the if you dont disable it from server side everytime the form submits the button will be enabled.do some server side operations.

Comment: @hey: When a form is submitted, the page will be unloaded and the target page will be loaded. You can't click the button again anyway. If you want to prevent the user from pressing the back-button and re-submitting the form, you should use a serverside transaction system that ignores further requests. You should be able to easily integrate that in the CSRF-protection.

Comment: @Bergi I don't want to prevent the user from using the browser's back functionality. I want to prevent it from pressing twice on the submit button. Do you get this ? The page is not unloaded as soon as you submit the the form. It takes some time...enough to press the button for multiple times... I guess you know that right ?

Comment: @hey: Ah, I had never encountered a page that loads slow enough or a browser that does send a second request. But still, you shouldn't tackle that problem with javascript, as it applies to non-js users as well. Just don't accept multiple requests with the same CRSF token.

Comment: The browser sends a request each time you press the button. You can send 10 requests or more if the page is loading slow enough. All the browsers do that. And yeah some pages are loading slow, especially if you are on mobile or if you are using some proxy stuff. How does the CRSF help ? Should I tell the user that he was bad and pressed the button for multiple times so now he won't get the order confirmation anymore ?

Answer (score -1):

You need to return true in order to submit the form. 
First write a javascript function as

```
   function BeforeLoginSubmitted(sender) {
            $(sender).prop("disabled", true);
            return true;
        }
```

Then in html button call the function as below

```
  <input id="loginBtn" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="login" value="Login"
            onclick="return BeforeLoginSubmitted(this);" />
```

Now the form will be submitted. If you return false in any case the form will not be submitted.

**Edit Below is the complete sample code for the page.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function BeforeLoginSubmitted(sender) {
            $(sender).prop("disabled", true);
            return true;
        }
     </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/" method="post" runat="server">

     <input id="loginBtn" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="login" value="Login"
     onclick="return BeforeLoginSubmitted(this);" />

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit 2** i see some issue with the above code in crome browser. The below code is working for the crome browser too.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function BeforeLoginSubmitted() {
           $("#loginBtn").prop("disabled", true);
            return true;
        }
     </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="https://www.google.com" method="post" onsubmit="return BeforeLoginSubmitted(this);" >

     <input id="loginBtn" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="login" value="Login"  />

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The button is disabled but the form is not submitted so it's not working.

Comment: @hey there could be some another problem with your code. I can see if you post your code in a fiddle. The solution that i have given is a very common one and used for validations etc.

Comment: The form is not being submitted... I don't need any validation. Just the form to be submitted and the button to be set to "disabled" to prevent the client to submit the same form for multiple times.

Comment: @hey please share your code in fiddle. The code i have provided works.

Comment: @hey in fiddle I would not be able to show submission functionality. I have edited my answer and posted full code for the page. Just save the code as an html file and run and try. In action you can give your desire path.

Comment: why fiddle would not show the submission functionality ? I can open the dev tool and watch if there is any post requested isn't it ? For the records I've also saved the html you posted and tested it but obviously is not working. I'm wondering how it worked on your side ? Did you see any POST request in the developer tool ?

Comment: @hey I see there is some problem with crome browser  for  the code i have given. I have modified the code and used form event onsubmit. Try the new code.

Answer (score -1):

This task can be simply done by ajax function :

Try this logic:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#loginBtn").click(function(){
    $("#loginBtn").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $.post("post file path here",
    {
      field1:"value1", //post data that will be used by other file
      field2:"value2",
      ..      ..  
    },
    function(response){
      if(response = "ok"){
          $("#loginBtn").prop('disabled', false);
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Listen to the **submit** event, not to the click event.

```
$("#form-id").on("submit", function () {
    $(this).find('[type="submit"]').attr("disabled","disabled");
});
```

Comment: The form is submitted but the button is not disabled

Answer (score -1):

This is an example ,

```
<div class="form-actions" id="frm"></div>

    $('#frm').bind('submit', function(e) {
        $('#loginBtn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        alert('submitted');

        validForm = false;    

        // do stuff (validations, etc) here and return false or e.preventDefault() if you want to stop the form from submitting 

        if (!validForm) { 
            e.preventDefault();
            // reactivate the button if the form was not submitted
            $('#loginBtn').prop('disabled',true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: is not working. The form is submitted but the button is not disabled

Comment: if u want to disabled the button permanently use,in if statement:
        $('#loginBtn').prop('disabled',true);

Comment: I should be able to both submit the form and disable the button. I'm simply trying to avoid a double click on a payment form page. Your code just disables the button but the form is not submitted anymore.

Comment: have you tried this -$('#loginBtn').prop('disabled',true);

Comment: the form is not being submitted. You only get an "alert" but no form data is submitted.  You can see that if you open the network / chrome dev tools